# There is no such driver by url - chromedriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, browser

my dears,

can you please help to solve the problem? My browser no longer opens during the run.
Thank you very much.

I got the following error since yesterday:

`ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_115.0.5790`

my code look like this at the beginning:

````
import pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)```
````

Answer (score 3):

`selenium` `4.10.0` and newer includes the driver manager, so you can do this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

If the driver isn't found on your system PATH, Selenium Manager will automatically download it.

---

If you're wondering why you're now seeing errors for `ChromeDriverManager`, it's because https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads only goes up to version 114 due to driver restructuring by the Chromium Team for the new [Chrome-for-Testing](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/).

---

There's also the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) Python selenium framework, which already has a fix for the Chrome 115 issue in the latest version: (After `pip install seleniumbase`, run the following with `python`):

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=False)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I am getting an error     service = Service()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'executable_path'

Comment: Make sure you're on the latest version of selenium. In https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1104c8f876011fc3fe11eb56d112a10312822866/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py#L34 - the args have defaults set for `Service()`.

Comment: Many thanks. I currently have a new problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78216281/chrome-window-appears-asking-who-was-currently-using-chrome  
can you help?