# Chrome window appears asking who was currently using Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

my dears,
I currently have a problem with my Selenium script. I suspect it's due to the Chrome driver.
When the script is executed and I want to go to a specific page, the Chrome window appears asking who was currently using Chrome and you can select the profiles there, but it quickly disappears and my program goes to error. My site used to open normally without this intermediate step with Chrome profiles.

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.95)
```

My script initially looks like this:

```
import time
import pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

url = "https://xxxxx.net/vpn/index.html"
driver.get(url)
```

Please help.
Many thanks.